# Создать всплывающее окно, которое затмит задний фон.

Tags: javascript, css

В интернете можно встретить, кучу всплывающих окон.

1.Как сделать эффект заднего затмения? css-фильтр на тег body? Но если pop-up тоже элемент body?
2. Как сделать, чтобы до закрытия окна, задний фон стал неактивен?

Answer (score 1):

Удалять вопрос на стал. 
Вот пример, кому может пригодится: http://jsfiddle.net/p7NbX/15/

Comment: только вместо jquery 2 используйте 1.9, а то в ишаке не работает